# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I'm getting error:

> Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

when I go to login `page.Login` page is separate template from home layout.then I created `login.component.ts` as `<router-outlet>` and `auth.component.ts` for my login page.

But home page working fine. error occur only load separate login page:

[image]

[image]

This is my folder structure:

[image]

`login.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

`login.route.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NoAuthGuard } from '../no-auth-guard.service';
import { AuthComponent } from '../login/auth.component';

export const AUTH_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AuthComponent,// canActivate: [NoAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login', component: AuthComponent,// canActivate: [NoAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'register', component: AuthComponent,// canActivate: [NoAuthGuard]
  }
]
```

`login.route.html`:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`auth.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Errors, UserService } from '../../shared';
import { UserLogin } from '../../shared/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'auth-page',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html'
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  authLoginForm: FormGroup;
  authRegisterForm: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private userService: UserService,  private fb: FormBuilder) {
   // use FormBuilder to create a form group   
   -- some code here
   // end use FormBuilder to create a form group
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  userLogin() { }
  userRegister() {}
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NoAuthGuard } from './auth/no-auth-guard.service';
import { HomeAuthResolver } from './layout/home-auth-resolver.service';

import { LoginComponent, AUTH_ROUTES } from './auth/index';
import {LayoutComponent,  PUBLIC_ROUTES } from './layout/index';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: AUTH_ROUTES },
    { path: 'register', component: LoginComponent,data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: AUTH_ROUTES },
    { path: '', component: LayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: the routes in your app-routing.module seems to conflict with the ones in login.routes.ts. Can't you remove login.routes.ts and refer to the AuthComponent directly?

Comment: yes I tried that but same error.  
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,data: { title: 'Public Views' }, loadChildren: './auth/login/auth.component' },

Comment: I would suggest to get rid of the login.routes. You don't want a url: /login/login and because of the empty routes: path: '', it cannot determine what route it should take. So refer to the Auth Component directly in the app-routes,  get rid of the children and change the path: '' to 'secure'. Another thing I don't understand is that you redirect to: home while there is no home route

Answer (score 0):

This problem lies in the ambiguity of your routing scheme. It's also worth noting the `Routes` is an array and thus ordered. Routes are evaluated in order they are defined in that array.

So move your *empty route* (`path: ''`) in `login.route.ts` to the last position in the `AUTH_ROUTES` array.